# How Do I Delete All Task Triggers For Each Task?

Tags: powershell

How do I delete all task triggers for each task altogether. The script below only removes the task trigger one at a time for one task. The script is written by Tony Hinkle.

```
$taskName = "MyTask"
$triggerToDelete = 1 (THIS PART, how do I write ALL)

# connect to Task Scheduler:
$service = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$service.Connect($env:COMPUTERNAME)

# pick a specific task in a container:
$folder = $service.GetFolder('\')
$task = $folder.GetTask($taskName)

# get task definition and change it:
$definition = $task.Definition
$definition.Triggers.Remove($triggerToDelete)

# write back changed task definition:
# 4 = Update
$folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($task.Name, $definition, 4, $null, $null, $null)
```

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/taskschd/triggercollection-clear) aren't hard to find, but even if you didn't have those, you could use `$definition.Triggers | Get-Member` to find out what you have available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate all the triggers backwards and delete them one by one.
Please note that trigger index is one based and not zero based.
Update: Added the code that enumerates all the tasks.

```
$service = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$service.Connect($env:COMPUTERNAME)

$folder = $service.GetFolder('\')

$tasks = $folder.gettasks(0)

foreach ($t in $tasks)
{
    $definition = $t.Definition

    $triggersCount = $definition.Triggers.Count

    for($id=$triggersCount; $id -gt 0; $id--){
      $definition.Triggers.Remove($id)   
    }

    $folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($t.Name, $definition, 4, $null, $null, $null)
}
```

Comment: Instead of $definition.Triggers.Remove($triggerToDelete), add the code i posted.

Comment: Where are the tasks located? you can change the name of the folder in GetFolder function.